# Artifactory virtual repo: Some files can't be downloaded (Zero bytes sent to client but expected XYZ bytes)

Tags: maven, virtual, artifactory

I am using Artifactory Pro version: 3.6.0. I have couple of remote repos (caches) configured proxying out to different external repos (like https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/...)
I also have a virtual repo configured which includes all the remote repos. (for example: http://mydomain/artifactory/remote-repos/...)

After Artifactory server restart I realized that some maven builds started failing because some of the maven plugin related pom files (dependencies)  can't be downloaded/fetched from Artifactory.

I noticed that the file can't be downloaded trough the virtual repo URL but can be downloaded trough the remote repo URL.

For example:

- Using remote repo direct URL (worked): http://mydomain/artifactory/**maven-apache-cache**/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom
- Using virtual repo url (did not worked): http://mydomain/artifactory/**remote-repos**/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom

(Just some 1-2 maven plugin related pom files can't be downloaded; The rest of the files downloaded okay.)

I need to use the virtual repo URL because that is how it is configured in settings.xml file (mirrored central cache)

I did a lot of different investigation:

1. Cleared the Artifactory proxy cache and all build server maven caches; These forced to re-cache the files
2. Looked at Artifactory logs (both info and debug levels)

   ...

   [DEBUG] (o.s.j.d.DataSourceUtils:110) - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

   [DEBUG] (o.a.s.d.u.JdbcHelper:98) - Query returned in 521032 nanos : 'SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE repo = 'remote-repos' AND node_path = 'org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26' AND node_name = 'maven-parent-26.pom''

   [DEBUG] (o.s.j.d.DataSourceUtils:327) - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

   [DEBUG] (o.a.r.RepoRequestContext:71) - 8b83e9a2 get admin remote-repos:org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom Identified requested resource as a file

   [DEBUG] (o.a.r.RepoRequestContext:71) - 8b83e9a2 get admin remote-repos:org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom Requested resource is an ordinary artifact - using normal content handle with length '40751'

   [DEBUG] (o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:523) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'pluginsAddonDefaultImpl'

   [DEBUG] (o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:523) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.artifactory.addon.plugin.PluginsAddonImpl#0'

   [DEBUG] (o.a.r.RepoRequestContext:71) - 8b83e9a2 get admin remote-repos:org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom Executing any BeforeDownload user plugins that may exist

   [DEBUG] (o.a.r.RepoRequestContext:71) - 8b83e9a2 get admin remote-repos:org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom Responding with selected content handle

   [DEBUG] (o.a.r.RequestResponseHelper:71) - Sending back body response for 'remote-repos:org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom'. Original resource size: 40751, actual size: 40751.

   [WARN ] (o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:57) - Zero bytes sent to client but expected 40751 bytes.

   [DEBUG] (o.a.r.RepoRequestContext:71) - 8b83e9a2 get admin remote-repos:org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom Request succeeded

   ...
3. Checked if file exists on Artifactory: Exists and can be downloaded using remote repo URL (not virtual repo URL); See above.
4. Tried to restart Artifactory couple of more times (restarted with no issue)
5. Created a new Artifactory virtual repo and started to use the new URL but same things happened than with the old one

Anybody has any idea why some of the files (like maven-parent-26.pom) can't be downloaded from Artifactory using the virtual repo URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed seems odd.
The only thing I can think of that can cause files not to be accessible in virtual is when you configured [include / exclude patterns](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories#VirtualRepositories-UsingIncludesandExcludesPatterns) in the virtual repository.
Maybe you can start by breaking it down and trying to resolve the pom file directly using curl once from remote repo like so:

```
curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-remote/path/to/pom
```

and once from virtual repo like so:

```
curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/my-virtual/path/to/pom
```

Make sure to only include this one remote repository in the virtual repository at first.

Comment: Also, try different repo other than Maven Central. Does the same happen with JCenter, for example?

Comment: Virtual repo include pattern is set to: **/* ; exclude pattern is set to empty so nothing is filtered out; But actually I tried to download the file today (which I was not able to download before) and there was not issue with it. It is so weird. Maybe artifactory did some internal indexing/cleanup during the weekend which fixed the issue.. Have no idea :-)

Comment: @JBaruch all other repo types (pypi, npm,...) were working correctly. The only problem I had is just couple of files (2-3) in maven type repos.

Comment: hm, did you try other maven repo, like JCenter?

Comment: I didn't but I do not want to spend more time on this... The issue disappeared.... (not happening anymore); If happens again I will further investigate.